# How reduce the time than takes get a bitmap

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, storage

I have a project on Android and iOS, there is a section where it shows a 360 view of a car, in iOS I just get the 60 images from internal storage that were previously downloaded from the internet, and these images are showed when the user starts to swipe the car to the right or to the left. And this process takes just 200ms to be ready to interact with the user.

But in Android I have to take first the 60 images and convert them in bitmaps, and then the process is similar to the iOS process. Nevertheless, this first process, convert all of them to bitmap takes about 3 seconds o more. I have read the process to show an image in Android in many sources of information and seems like is necessary use a bitmap for this task, so is possible to reduce the time to get all bitmaps?, or could I save a  bitmap to avoid converting the PNG file again to a new bitmap when the users open the same view again?

The code that I'm using to convert png  file to a bitmap object is the same that Android developers documentation recommend:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap

My source code for get bitmap is:

```
   public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    options.inSampleSize = 1;
    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    Log.d("img360","bitmap res "+bitmap.getWidth()+ " h "+bitmap.getHeight());
    return bitmap;
}
```

I'm really thankful for your help and support.

Comment: I think you can use this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String) instead of https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile(java.lang.String,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options) so you don't need options

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize `1` is equals to `0`

Comment: This can improve the performance.

Comment: And if you want specific size you can use this too https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)

Comment: Why I comment all this is because in computing is generally read file is more slow than read in memory but this can do outofmemory if the picture is too large

Answer (score -2):

If you want to  download images from Internet  and display them on android
Just put an imageview and use picaso or glide library
It is faster and easier